# Missing __requestVerificationToken in HTML

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, httprequest, antiforgerytoken, csrf-token

My goal is to upload a file via HTTP POST Request in JMeter. However, this POST request requires a __RequestVerificationToken, which is missing in the HTML of the page.

**The problem**: While I was able to

- *find* & *extract* the anti-forgery token in the HTML of the login page & successfully *login* in,
- there is no token in the HTML of the upload page to upload the file via POST request.

However, if you look at the Request Headers of an example /UploadFile POST request (or any GET request of that page) in the browser, you can see that an anti-forgery token has been used, that differ from the token used for logging in.

**Error**: The provided anti-forgery token is not correct for the current user.

Both requests have the same Cookies (incl. Token). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the **previous** response body or [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), you need to take a closer look and you will see it.

If you cannot detect the token you can use your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to record your test case traffic and save it into [HAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) file (which is basically a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)-like structure). Use your favourite text/JSON viewer/editor and look for the token, I'm 100% sure you will be able to find it somewhere in the previous response.

More information: [What is CSRF & How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-csrf-load-testing)